# while working with java mail in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, email

I used the code from [here](http://www.roseindia.net/mail/sending-an-email-in-jsp.shtml)

I am following it as it is, but while executing I got errors as below

```
2014-03-06 16:27:33,203 - [SMTPSender] SMTPSender - Delivery failed for message from: nbarath2008@gmail.com to: nbarath2008@gmail.com - java.lang.RuntimeException: SMTP Response too short. Aborting Send. Response: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: SMTP Response too short. Aborting Send. Response: 
    at com.ericdaugherty.mail.server.services.smtp.SMTPRemoteSender.read(SMTPRemoteSender.java:380)
    at com.ericdaugherty.mail.server.services.smtp.SMTPRemoteSender.sendIntro(SMTPRemoteSender.java:270)
    at com.ericdaugherty.mail.server.services.smtp.SMTPRemoteSender.sendMessage(SMTPRemoteSender.java:122)
    at com.ericdaugherty.mail.server.services.smtp.SMTPSender.deliverRemoteMessage(SMTPSender.java:361)
    at com.ericdaugherty.mail.server.services.smtp.SMTPSender.deliver(SMTPSender.java:184)
    at com.ericdaugherty.mail.server.services.smtp.SMTPSender.run(SMTPSender.java:100)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)`
```

Please guide me, thank you.

Comment: have you tested your mail server? Have you got access to mail server?

Comment: yes i downloaded jes.email.server.launcher_1.0.0 for eclipse,but how can i test and i i have another doubt now is there any something account creation like that, i don't know please guide me

Comment: what value u have given in code  instead of localhost ? in this line transport.connect("localhost",25,null,null);

Comment: just i write transport.connect("localhost",25,"username","password"); is it wrong

Comment: You can use Gmail SMTP. Take a look at here http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Comment: @kumar u have to give SMTP server ip address instead of loclhost there..

Comment: thanks for ur response u mean like this transport.connect("mail.smtp.",25,"username","password");

Comment: no @kumar ..first of all. do u have any mail(SMTP) server ....if not use the gmail smtp server and send..

Comment: i dont have smtp server, i used smtp.gmail.com as a hostname but i got error like 'Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mail.com, port: 25, response: -1'

Comment: try this link, will lessen your work https://code.google.com/p/simple-java-mail/